# Unity - determine if textures are not used, such as "blank" normal texture and black occlusion texture etc

Tags: unity, textures, optimization

To try to optimize for runtime load of arbitrary 3D models, many of which have "fake normal textures" (basically, just a flat shade of purple - does not really add much to the look), how do you determine if certain textures are not null but effectively are "blank" or "fake" in a performant way that can load 8K or higher textures without running into memory issues?

This works for smaller textures but crashes for larger ones on mobile:

````
bool CheckIfSolidColor(Texture tex)
    {
        Texture2D tex2d = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height ,TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;

        RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture(tex2d.width, tex2d.height, 32);
        Graphics.Blit(tex, renderTexture);

        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        tex2d.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        tex2d.Apply();

        Color[] colors = tex2d.GetPixels();
        Color last = colors[0] ;
        for(int i = 1; i < colors.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colors[i] != last) return false;

            last = colors[i];
        }
        return true;
    }

```
````

Comment: Presumably you considered writing a script that loops over the pixels of the texture and checks whether their values are all within some threshold? Where did you run into a specific problem with this that we can help you solve?

Comment: Performance for extremely large textures.

Comment: Also .mainTexture is not a Texture2D, so GetColor requires conversion processes before to Texture2D

Comment: updated with a snippet that works for small textures but crashes for 4k and 8k ones

Comment: @ina Have you considered to not use `ReadPixels` for the whole texture at once but only for one section of it at a time?

Comment: Although I wonder what's the idea behind doing this on the device. Doing this as an editor script to detect poorly designed assets during development and tell the artist to stop adding pointless textures? Sure. But why do it at runtime? Optimize loading time? You need to load the texture in order to check if its blank, so what would be gained by that?

Comment: Well, it's for user imported 3d models at runtime - it seems many general 3D software export and embed useless normals and albedo that are just a single color